# SQL Server implicit casting to VARCHAR(MAX)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, casting

I have a SQL function with following signature

```
(  
  @value as VARCHAR(MAX)
) 
RETURNS NCHAR(47)
```

What will happen if the input of the function will be `int`?

Implicit casting to `VARCHAR(MAX)`?

i.e if the input is `int 12` how will it be transferred to the function input leading zeros and 12 - "`000000..000012`"

Comment: No, it will just be read as '12'

Comment: You aren't actually storing data like that ina varchar (max) field are you, that is very poor idea unless the field is often going to contain more than 8000 characters

Answer (score 0):

It gets cast to varchar but there will be no leading 0's, it will simply be read as 12. Just because you specify varchar(max) doesn't mean it will use the space it has and automatically fill it with 0's.